# Will I be able to access my encrypted home folder if I reset my lost password on Ubuntu 16.04.4?

Tags: 16.04, password, encryption

I installed Ubuntu with the *encrypt home folder* option but I have forgotten my root password. If I reset my password, will I be able to I gain access to my encrypted home folder?

Comment: Do you have the unwrapped passphrase (a long string of hex digits) that you were told to copy down the first time you logged in after encrypting your home directory?

Comment: No I don't have it. :(

Comment: Sorry ubuntu version is 16.04.4 not 17.10 can you remove the hold on the question?

Answer (score 0):

Without the unwrapped passphrase (or your forgotten password), you will be unable gain access to the files in your home directory.

If you have the unwrapped passphrase, it is a different story.